# How to insert image into sqlite3 database?

Tags: python, sql, opencv, blob

Here is part of my code:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter
import time
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageTk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, Toplevel

r=Tk()
conn = sqlite3.connect('datastorage.db')
print("Opened database successfully");

def snapshot(self):
             # Get a frame from the video source
            ret, frame = self.vid.get_frame()
```

I am capturing a frame from video and I need to insert it into a database which contains a text column and a blob(Binary Large Object) column. There are other similar questions which suggest converting to string and storing but since I already have images in blob format stored and I am extracting them using decode as seen in the code below, I need to store blob only.

```
blob_data=row[1]
                nparr  = np.frombuffer(blob_data, np.uint8)
                img_np = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                image1=cv2.resize(img_np,(260,200))
                #cv2.imshow("data",image1)
                #break
                #Rearrang the color channel
                b,g,r = cv2.split(image1)
                image1 = cv2.merge((r,g,b))
                hsv1=cv2.cvtColor(image1, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
                kernel2 = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
```

I tried using the following query:

```
cursor=conn.execute("create table if not exists user_6 (id text, img blob)")
cursor=conn.execute("insert into user_6 values (?,?)",(ins,sqlite3.Binary(frame)))
```

but I am unable to display it using the same method I used to display all the other entries. The code used to display is the 2nd code block. I am encountering an error as shown:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Python tut\gui databse.py", line 71, in display
    image1=cv2.resize(img_np,(130,100))
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using the following code:

```
img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tostring()
cursor=conn.execute("create table if not exists user_6 (id text, img blob)")
cursor=conn.execute("insert into user_6 values (?,?)",(ins,img_str))
conn.commit()
```

Although the colors in the image are different from the captured image.